# how to solve unmet dependencies when install libgstreamer0.10-dev?

Tags: debian, dependencies

I want to run genymotion 64bit binary on my debian 8.3 64bit. when I run `./genymotion` command I get this error:

```
./genymotion: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed the command that mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869830/genymotion-error-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) but I get this error (how ever he tried that in ubuntu):

```
╰─$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev                                            100 ↵
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgstreamer0.10-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your immediate issue is running `genymotion`, this should be enough to fix the first error you reported:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```